# Node.js Object object has no method 'hasOwnProperty'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Not sure why `hasOwnProperty()` seems to be missing from my object...

I'm getting data from an http post in expressjs3, like this:

```
someControllerFunction: function(req, res){
            var data = req.body.loc;
...
}
```

However if I do:

```
data.hasOwnProperty('test');
```

I get:

```
Object object has no method 'hasOwnProperty'
```

**Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but what?**

*(Node 10.5, Express 3.2.1)*

Comment: I tested and noticed that the `req` object (and thus also `req.body`) allow `.hasOwnProperty` as of Express v3.4.8 (whereas I had also noticed this issue in a previous release.)(I cannot tell from the [Express releases](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/releases) which update fixed this as changelogs are not noted before v3.5.3.)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The object may not have `Object.prototype` as its prototype.

This is the case if the object was created with...

```
var data = Object.create(null);
```

You could use...

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, 'test');
```

...to test if the property exists.

Comment: `Object.hasOwnProperty.call(data, "test")` is shorter and works just as well. This is generally considered the safe way of calling hasOwnProperty, because hasOwnProperty could indeed not exist, or could be given a different value in the object under consideration.

Comment: @MerynStol If shortness is what you're after, you could use `"".hasOwnProperty.call(data, "test")` :)

Comment: @alex Thanks - I'll use the safe test you suggested.  Still - I find it very strange that the object created by the express body parser doesnt have the prototype set properly.  Perhaps it's a bug - I'll post with the express guys too.

Comment: @alex True, but actually constructing an object (in two phases, first a (primitive) string, then a String) goes a bit too far for me.

Comment: @MerynStol Indeed, and I'd never recommend anyone use it. One slightly better thing about `Object.prototype` over `Object` is it doesn't require traveling the prototype chain, though it would hardly ever matter.

Comment: @alex yes. Well to be absolutely clear (I can't edit my earlier comment), in "This is generally considered the safe way of calling hasOwnProperty," with "This", I was referring to the practice of getting a safe reference to `hasOwnProperty` (i.e. from the `Object` prototype), not my particular way of doing it.

Answer (score -2):

This hack works for me:

```
req.body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
```

Comment: That's a lot of work just so you can get `Object.prototype` on the prototype.

Comment: This isn't good practice at all, those JSON functions are expensive operations.